# SSHFS recognised SSH Key, still asks for password

Tags: sshfs, autofs

I had no problem using sshfs and autofs and my server was doing OK.

I am mounting my backup server as a drive on my actual server.

But suddenly I noticed it is no longer mounting the backup drive.

This is the log that I get when I run the following command:

```
sshfs -o debug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa user@myBackupServer.com:/ /storage_box/backup


debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myBackupServer.com [*****:3000::85] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version mod_sftp
debug1: no match: mod_sftp
debug1: Authenticating to myBackupServer.com:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:*************
debug1: Host 'myBackupServer.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

This line says server accepted my id_rsa?

```
Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

why It still asks for password?

Comment: It is because you used ~ in the key path so when you run. The command as root it is looking in /root . Use the full path to the key

Comment: I added my root ssh key to authorised_keys on backup server. So I think it is correct. (I also tried using /root/.ssh/id_rsa)